# PHP resize an image without saving a file

Tags: php, image, gd, image-resizing

I have images that are displayed as thumbnails on my site. The size of thumbnails varies a lot. Ideally, I would not have to save a copy of each photo in each thumbnail's dimensions. Rather, I could specify in PHP the final dimensions, and have the image resized before it is sent from the server.

I am **not** trying to resize a photo when it is being uploaded to the server. I am **not** able to save an image as each thumbnails size.

The issue is that the thumbnails vary in size depending the pages layout. So if I save the image as each thumbnail size, I will save about 20x the number of photos I have.

I have tried saving a 'small' 'medium' and 'large' image, and then I call the one which is closest to the thumbnail size. Seemed a bit crude, but it sounds like this may be the proper method.

Comment: You're asking to resize images "on the fly" in every petition? You must consider saving the resizes files for performance.

Comment: I think @Donny P wants set the image tag size attribute, something like height="120px".

Comment: most of time the expert question get negative rank :(

Answer (score 3):

Well, as you don't want to exhaust you disk space, you will exhaust your CPU resources, which is much worse.
Even if you *think* that you're unable to save thumbnails on the disk, you'll have to. There is no other way. You'd just waste your time and eventually turn to proper setup.

Comment: Ah, the Colonel is back... let's see for how long this time. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have done something similar, what you could do is something like this, like previously posted this can use up lots of resources, and saving to disk is usually better, but if you really want to, give this a shot:

```
<?php

function createThumbnail($filename, $thumbWidth){
    $details = getimagesize($filename);
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $srcImg = imagecreatefromstring($content);
    $thumbHeight = $details[1] * ($thumbWidth / $details[0]);
    $thumbImg = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $details[0], $details[1]);
    imagejpeg($thumbImg, null, 100);
    imagedestroy($srcImg);
    return $thumbImg;
}

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo createThumbnail("/path/to/image.jpg", 200);
```

Comment: As pointed out above, this is an *immense* strain on resources.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this would be of course to calculate image sizes and return `img` tags with appropriate attributes like this:

```
"<img width=\"" . $width . "px\" height=\"" . $height . "\" src="..."/>"
```

Resizing images "on the fly" is just too time consuming. Consider the case where you show 20 images each one would be scaled consuming 150ms (depending on the size of the image and scale factor). This will be approximately over 3 seconds to display a single page. Do you really want to force users to wait such a long period of time to see the contents of the page?